# How to set velocity in Swift

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

Below is an Enemy node in Sprite Kit, in Swift. I have set the velocity for the node, but when it spawns there is no movement. Xcode is giving me no errors, is there something I'm doing wrong here?

```
class Enemy: SKSpriteNode {

    init(imageNamed: String) {

        let imageTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: imageNamed)
        super.init(texture: imageTexture, color: nil, size: imageTexture.size())

        self.name = "Enemy"

        self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: imageTexture.size())
        self.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
        self.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVectorMake(10.0,10.0)

    }
}
```

Comment: Use skaction to make movements

Comment: You need to set `self.physicsBody?.dynamic = true`.

Comment: African or European Swift? :) Actually, @0x141E has the answer. You can't make a static body move.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From Apple's [SpriteKit documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/Documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKPhysicsBody/dynamic):

> A Boolean value that indicates whether the physics body is moved by the physics simulation.
>
> **Declaration**
>
> *Swift*
>
> `var dynamic: Bool`
>
> *Objective-C*
>
> `@property(nonatomic, getter=isDynamic) BOOL dynamic`
>
> **Discussion**
>
> If the value is NO, the physics body ignores all forces and impulses applied to it. This property is ignored on edge-based bodies; they are automatically static.

As 0x141E says, you have to make your `SKPhysicsBody` dynamic, or it won't move.